# Get the average of rates per assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-manipulation, normalization

I have the following data:

```
{
  "students": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Barbara" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Grace" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "John" },
],
"assignments": [   
{
    "id": 1,
    "name_id": 1,
    "assignment": "Mathematics",
    "assignment_difficulty": 3,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name_id": 1,
    "assignment": "Science",
    "assignment_difficulty": 3,
    "assignment_fun": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name_id": 1,
    "assignment": "German",
    "assignment_difficulty": 1,
    "assignment_fun": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name_id": 1,
    "assignment": "French",
    "assignment_difficulty": 2,
    "assignment_fun": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name_id": 1,
    "assignment": "Sports",
    "assignment_difficulty": 5,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  }
{
    "id": 6,
    "name_id": 2,
    "assignment": "Science",
    "assignment_difficulty": 4,
    "assignment_fun": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name_id": 2,
    "assignment": "Biology",
    "assignment_difficulty": 2,
    "assignment_fun": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name_id": 2,
    "assignment": "English",
    "assignment_difficulty": 1,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name_id": 2,
    "assignment": "French",
    "assignment_difficulty": 3,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name_id": 2,
    "assignment": "Sports",
    "assignment_difficulty": 2,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
{
    "id": 11,
    "name_id": 3,
    "assignment": "Mathematics",
    "assignment_difficulty": 1,
    "assignment_fun": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name_id": 3,
    "assignment": "Biology",
    "assignment_difficulty": 3,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name_id": 3,
    "assignment": "English",
    "assignment_difficulty": 4,
    "assignment_fun": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name_id": 3,
    "assignment": "German",
    "assignment_difficulty": 3,
    "assignment_fun": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name_id": 3,
    "assignment": "Sports",
    "assignment_difficulty": 2,
    "assignment_fun": 5
  }
]
```

Now I need to calculate the average difficulty and fun rates per assignment. As you can see, not every student has the same assignments.

What approach is the best when starting blanco. `.map()`? Or better `for (var i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++){//do something}` methode?

I assume it is wise to first iterate over the assignments by students and iterate within that iterate over the rates.

Or is wiser to iterate over the persons first and within that iteration over the assignments and its rates for that person?

Comment: I don't think you need to iterate over persons at all.  You need to group yourData.assignments by assignment, and then in each group find the average difficulty/fun scores.  Normally "group by" stuff implies using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/535480

Comment: What is the expected / desired output? Is it an object, an array - what are its elements / contents?

Comment: An array of objects, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do some `reduce` magic but this what I find easier to read and understand for others coming across your code:

```
const grouped = {} // initialize this

// Gather assignment data for calculations
data.assignments.forEach(({ assignment, assignment_fun, assignment_difficulty }) => {
  if (grouped[assignment]) {
    grouped[assignment].assignment_fun = grouped[assignment].assignment_fun + assignment_fun
    grouped[assignment].assignment_difficulty = grouped[assignment].assignment_difficulty + assignment_difficulty
    grouped[assignment].count = grouped[assignment].count + 1
  } else
    grouped[assignment.assignment] = {
      tFun: assignment.assignment_fun,
      tDifficulty: assignment.assignment_difficulty,
      count: 1
    }
}}

// finally calculate results per assignment
Object.keys(grouped).forEach((assignment) => {
  const count = grouped[assignment].count;
  console.log(`${assignment} Average Difficulty: ${grouped[assignment].tDifficulty/count}`)
  console.log(`${assignment} Average Fun: ${grouped[assignment].tFun/count}`)
})
```

Comment: Hey,
My earlier comments are gone! 
Can you explain step by step what you are actually doing with this code? When I apply this in my code it throws 'undefined''s to me, so I want to alter it, but I can only do that when I can get my finger behind it....